# Find top N elements in a Multiset from Google Collections?

Tags: java, guava, multiset

A [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) is a set of elements each of which has a count (i.e. may be present multiple times).

I can't tell you how many times I want to do the following

1. Make a histogram (exactly Multiset)
2. Get the top N elements by count from the histogram

Examples: top 10 URLs (by # times mentioned), top 10 tags (by # times applied), ...

What is the canonical way to do #2 given a Google Collections Multiset?

[Here](http://philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/02/20/a-generic-method-for-sorting-google-collections-multiset-per-entry-count/) is a blog post about it, but that code is not quite what I want.  First, it returns everything, not just top N.  Second, it copies (is it possible to avoid a copy?). Third, I usually want a deterministic sort, i.e. tiebreak if counts are equal.  Other nits: it's not static, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote methods with the basic functionality you're asking for, except that they perform copies and lack deterministic tie-breaking logic. They're currently internal to Google, but we may open-source them at some point. This Guava [issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=356) has the method signatures.

Their algorithm is similar to the blog post: sorting a list of entries. It would be faster, but more complicated, to use a better [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements).

EDIT: since Guava 11, this is [implemented](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst%28com.google.common.collect.Multiset%29)

Comment: how to use it to get top N elements?

Answer (score 3):

To give another perspective for people to comment on, I'll post a slightly modified version of the blog post I referenced:

```
package com.blueshiftlab.twitterstream.summarytools;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset.Entry;

public class Multisets {
    // Don't construct one
    private Multisets() {
    }

    public static <T> ImmutableList<Entry<T>> sortedByCount(Multiset<T> multiset) {
        Ordering<Multiset.Entry<T>> countComp = new Ordering<Multiset.Entry<T>>() {
            public int compare(Multiset.Entry<T> e1, Multiset.Entry<T> e2) {
                return e2.getCount() - e1.getCount();
            }
        };
        return countComp.immutableSortedCopy(multiset.entrySet());
    }

    public static <T> ImmutableList<Entry<T>> topByCount(Multiset<T> multiset,
            int max) {
        ImmutableList<Entry<T>> sortedByCount = sortedByCount(multiset);
        if (sortedByCount.size() > max) {
            sortedByCount = sortedByCount.subList(0, max);
        }

        return sortedByCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this solution will copy and sort the entire collection every time you want to retrieve the top N elements.  I'm not sure what your requirements are, but the heap-sort-ish solution beats this in both time and space so I'm not sure what the benefit is.

Comment: You are optimizing for speed, I am looking for fewest # of lines of code written by me.

Comment: I see - that was not clear from your post, especially since you asked about avoiding making a copy.

Comment: careful, your comparator is sorting by count descending

Comment: Good point.  That is by design, but not called out explicitly. "top N" usually means descending sort.

Comment: @dfrankow: I know, but if I called `sortedByCount()` I would expect it to be the other way around :)